# getting an error object not found in r in quantmod

Tags: r, quantmod

This is my code

```
library(quantmod)
library(quadprog)

daily_return=function(x)
{
   d=length(x)
   return(log(x[2:d]/x[1:(d-1)]))
}

P56=BHARATFORG["20100401::20140331",6]
R56=daily_return(as.numeric(P56[,1]))
```

But I am getting an error that

```
Error: Object 'BHARATFORG' not found
```

Can anyone help me what can I do for this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the object `BHARATFORG` exist?

Comment: Actually I am trying to get data of BHARATFORG from yahoo finance for that particular period i.e. 2010 to 2014

Comment: Can you show us the code where you are trying to get the data from Yahoo! Finance?

Comment: Thats the code what I write. That's it. Is that wrong or is that need addition

Comment: Well, then you have clearly not read the quantmod manual. Please read it to understand how to download data from Yahoo! Finance.

Comment: Yep, I got the answer thank you so much